# Simple form require integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm a junior ruby on rails developer. I made a scaffold using simple form; unfortunately, i forgot to declare a field as an integer. Can you please help?

I think i need to add a validation on the model, i've read other github issues although i'm confused.

I want the monthly repeats field as a integer.

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @clinic_compliance_task]) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :title %>
<%= f.input :monthly_repeat_frequency %>
<%= f.input :description %>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 </div>
 <% end %>



class ClinicComplianceTask < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: Do you need the whole steps from: 1. change db column, 2. adding validator to model 3. changing form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number_field: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/number_field

```
<%= f.number_field :monthly_repeat_frequency %>
```

---

If it's also part of your problem:

1. Add a new migration and change db column type
2. Adding validator to model
3. Change Form

your migration

```
change_column :clinic_compliance_tasks, :monthly_repeat_frequency, :integer
```

in the model

```
 validates_numericality_of :monthly_repeat_frequency, only_integer: true
```

in the form

```
 <%= f.number_field :monthly_repeat_frequency %>
```

Comment: If the answer helped, you can mark it as correct ;)